# Can't find children leafs using elementtree.find()

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to output the text "Det norske Arbeiderparti" from the last line of the xml file below. I am using this code but I get the error shown:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('wiki.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root.find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}title').text)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This is the XML:

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd" version="0.10" xml:lang="nb">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Wikipedia</sitename>
    <dbname>nowiki</dbname>
    <base>https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Forside</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.31.0-wmf.12</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">Medium</namespace>
      <namespace key="-1" case="first-letter">Spesial</namespace>
      <namespace key="0" case="first-letter" />
      <namespace key="1" case="first-letter">Diskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="2" case="first-letter">Bruker</namespace>
      <namespace key="3" case="first-letter">Brukerdiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="4" case="first-letter">Wikipedia</namespace>
      <namespace key="5" case="first-letter">Wikipedia-diskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="6" case="first-letter">Fil</namespace>
      <namespace key="7" case="first-letter">Fildiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="8" case="first-letter">MediaWiki</namespace>
      <namespace key="9" case="first-letter">MediaWiki-diskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="10" case="first-letter">Mal</namespace>
      <namespace key="11" case="first-letter">Maldiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="12" case="first-letter">Hjelp</namespace>
      <namespace key="13" case="first-letter">Hjelpdiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="14" case="first-letter">Kategori</namespace>
      <namespace key="15" case="first-letter">Kategoridiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="100" case="first-letter">Portal</namespace>
      <namespace key="101" case="first-letter">Portaldiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="828" case="first-letter">Modul</namespace>
      <namespace key="829" case="first-letter">Moduldiskusjon</namespace>
      <namespace key="2300" case="first-letter">Gadget</namespace>
      <namespace key="2301" case="first-letter">Gadget talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="2302" case="case-sensitive">Gadget definition</namespace>
      <namespace key="2303" case="case-sensitive">Gadget definition talk</namespace>
      <namespace key="2600" case="first-letter">Sak</namespace>
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>Det norske Arbeiderparti</title>
```

I know my search name is correct because this code yields the right name:

```
print(root.getchildren()[1].getchildren())

<Element '{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}title' at 0x1101ff188>
```

The only way I can actually find what I want is to use this code, but I can't use that for the entire xml as the names are in different places:

```
print(root.getchildren()[1].find('{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}title').text)

Det norske Arbeiderparti
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from etree Documentation

> find(match)
>   Finds the first **subelement** matching match. match may be a tag name or path. Returns an element instance or None.

So you should try xpath.

This should work:

```
print(root.find('.//{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}title').text)
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a million!